# How to write MagickImage to SdCard?

Tags: android, imagemagick, fileoutputstream

I am using MagickImage library to process the images.I want to store the images in the Sd Card after processing.I have used following code for that but of no avail:

```
images[i] = new MagickImage(new ImageInfo(path));
MagickImage image = new MagickImage(images);
image =  image.charcoalImage(20.0, 40.0);

File m_file = new File(path);
if(! m_file.exists())
{
    m_file.mkdirs();                 
}
File file = new File(path1);
if(!file.exists())
{
    file.createNewFile();
 }

 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path2);                            
 fos.write(image.toBytes());    
 fos.flush();
 fos.close();
```

Here i am getting problem in fos.write(image.toBytes()); Please tell me how to solve this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error are you getting. People are not some kind of magician.

Comment: Actually sir the  fos.write(image.toBytes()); method does not apply to the MagickImage img.I just want to know hoe to convert the image into bytes,so as to write it into the sdcard using outputstream.

Comment: but the "toBytes()" method exits?

Comment: toBytes() is not applicable for the image processed by the MagickImage i.e image ,in this case

Comment: so it is a different way to say: No the MagickImage api does not expose the toBytes() method, am I right?

Comment: Any other way for achieving the goal sir?

Comment: What is your MagickImage version in recent version you have .TobyteArray()   and you can use that one. But before you go for that solution let me ask you something why you are not using the .Write() command you can .Write MagickImage with any format you want into any path. Do I miss something ? is this SD card something different that a normal storage ? and If you use the .Write() command you can have twice performance while converting MagickImage to ByteArray is time consuming and again write it to stream is again heavy process. So if you use one Write command that would be much faster.